# XSLT get empty TAG name

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to find out the profession of these two people, where a different trade can appear optionally. So I would like to find out the name of all the labels that are empty like this:

```
<artists>
    <artist name="Ghiberti">
      <name>Lorenzo Ghiberti </name>
      <birth>1378</birth>
      <death>1455</death>
      <goldsmith /> <!-- This -->
      <sculptor /> <!-- This -->
    </artist>
    <artist name="Donatello">
      <name>Donato di Niccolò di Betto Bardi</name>
      <birth>1386</birth>
      <death>1466</death>
      <sculptor /> <!-- This -->
    </artist>
 </artists>
```

I already have the structure made and I get all the data of the person, but I do not get the name of that label. I would like to get this:

```
Miguel Ángel Buonarroti ( goldsmith, sculptor ) birth in 1475 and death in 1564
Giorgio Vasari (sculptor ) birth in 1511 and death in 1574
```

this is my actual code:

```
<xsl:template match="artists">
    <h2> Artist florecian </h2>
    <xsl:for-each select="artist">
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/> (
    birth in <xsl:value-of select="birth"/> and death in <xsl:value-of select="death"/> <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>    
      </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML structure is wrong. Try again with:

```
<artists>
    <artist name="Ghiberti">
      <name>Lorenzo Ghiberti </name>
      <birth>1378</birth>
      <death>1455</death>
      <profession>goldsmith</profession>
      <profession>sculptor</profession>
    </artist>
    <artist name="Donatello">
      <name>Donato di Niccolò di Betto Bardi</name>
      <birth>1386</birth>
      <death>1466</death>
      <profession>sculptor</profession>
    </artist>
 </artists>
```

Think about why you chose `<name>...</name>` but not `<profession>...</profession>`. Your XSLT will get very straightforward with this change, I'm sure you don't need help with that.

Of course you can get the name of a node with the [`name()` XPath function](https://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-functions/#name), but in this case it's not the correct solution.

Comment: I think it's a subjective matter where this design choice is right or wrong - in the end it's just semantics.

Comment: No, that's not subjective, really. There clearly is a worse way and a better way of doing things here, and it's pretty clear from the question that the XML structure is the OP's own choice. Of course everybody is free to shoot themselves in the foot, but I refuse to be complicit in the foot-shooting. I rather point out the better way of approaching a task.

Comment: *"it's pretty clear from the question that the XML structure is the OP's own choice."* I don't see that.

Comment: Well, they have your version of a solution to go with then. I maintain that they have a beginner's mistake in their XML structure and will be much better off correcting it than working around it.

Comment: I am not saying the XML structure is not flawed. I just don't see the part where it's clear it's their own choice.

Comment: I know, and we don't disagree. It's not explicitly stated. It's my conclusion, you might have come to a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="artists">
    <h2> Artist florecian </h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="artist">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[not(text())]/name()" separator=", "/>
            <xsl:text>) birth in </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="birth"/>
            <xsl:text> and death in </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="death"/> 
            <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y98

Comment: An element with no text node child is not an empty element.